# Index document "linked" to multiple users

Tags: solr

Hi I want to index a Solr Document and tag the document with multiple associated users. I want to enable searches like "give me the documents assocaited with userid 1000,1003...9300 containing the word X.  More people will be added to the document during the lifetime of the document. I want to potentially associate thousands of users to one document. There is no need to show the associated users in the results, just for search, will indexing of userid or username be more performant and scalable. What field type would be more performant and scalable, appending to a text field, a multivalued field or any other approach?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that using the userid (as an integer) would be the most performant. (At least from my experience so far). Also, using a multivalued field will allow you to use a filter query on the userid field to help improve the query response time.